# bokeh: interactive slider in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, interactive

I want to add some interactive sliders for bokeh plots. This has been done using bokeh server. [This file](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.4.3/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb) shows how this is implemented.

However, it only works in web browser, but not in Visual Studio Code, because [Bokeh server doesn't yet support VScode](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10765#issuecomment-739543791).

Is there any other way to add interactive sliders in VSCode?